# Multiple Color Styles in a single console.log()?

Tags: javascript, css, console, styling, console.log

I have an array of hex values,

```
"colors": ["#d5dd90","#e6bb45","#ef9770"]
```

I can log these out like this:

```
colors.forEach((value)=>{
  console.log('%cABC', `background: ${value};`);
})
```

which results in 3 separate `console.log()` entries:

`ABC`

`______________`

`ABC`

`______________`

`ABC`

`______________`

Each 'ABC' being a different color, one `log()` called for each item in the array.

What I'd like to do write each item in one line, like so:

`ABC`
`ABC`
`ABC`

`______________`

So basically have one `log()` call for each array, each styled with its respective color.

I can do that here:
let colors= ["#d5dd90","#e6bb45","#ef9770"]
console.log('%cABC %cABC %cABC', `color:${colors[0]}`, `color:${colors[1]}`, `color:${colors[2]}`);

I have multiple arrays, so I'd need to do this within a `for()` loop, which is the part I'm having trouble with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%c` can be used multiple times in the string to log.

```js
const colors = ["#d5dd90","#e6bb45","#ef9770"];
console.log(colors.map(c => `%c${c}`).join(''), ...colors.map(c => `background: ${c};`));
```

```html
Open the browser console to see the result
```